# Most pythonic game board representation for Tic-Tac-Toe?

Tags: python, tic-tac-toe

Which would be the most pythonic way to represent the game board and winning combinations for a tic-tac-toe game in python?

I started with the first solution, thinking it would be more object oriented to have the game tiles as separate objects maintaining their own state in a two dimensional array:

```
class GameTile:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.value = None  # value is either "x", "o", or None

class GameBoard:
    _board_size = 3
    _player = "o"
    _computer = "x"

    def __init__(self):
        # generate the tile set
        self.tiles = [[GameTile(x, y) for y in range(GameBoard._board_size)] for x in range(GameBoard._board_size)]

        # generate winning combos
        self.winning_combos = [col for col in self.tiles] + \  #vertical
                          [[col[i] for col in self.tiles] for i in range(GameBoard._board_size)] + \  # horizontal
                          [[self.tiles[i][i] for i in range(GameBoard._board_size)]] + \  #diagonal
                          [[self.tiles[i][GameBoard._board_size - i - 1] for i in range(GameBoard._board_size)]]  #diagonal
```

However, now the more I look at it, the more it seems that the board could be represented more simply as a single list of values that represent the moves, and a list of winning combos that don't need to be defined dynamically:

```
class GameBoard:
    _board_size = 3
    _player = "o"
    _computer = "x"
    _winning_combos = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], etc...]

    def __init__(self):
        self.board = [None] * 9
```

The second approach is much simpler, but is it the most pythonic way to do it? Or am I even asking the correct question?

Also, in the second example would the winning combos be better as a list of tuples since it is immutable? Or would that create inefficiencies when calculating the winner since it would be comparing to a list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're over-engineering your solution.

I don't know if it's the most pythonic way, but the most rational way of doing it would be using a 2D matrix of integers, or strings, but certainly not `GameTile` objects. Why? Why do you need an additional class when an integer or a string would hold all the information you need? The position is implicit within the matrix, and the value of the tile is stored using an integer (0 empty, 1 first player, 2 second player) or a string.

```
matrix = [[0 for y in range(3)] for x in range(3)]
```

It doesn't get easier than that.

Comment: Thank you. I've been overthinking this thing too much and second guessing myself.  I needed someone else affirm what I was thinking.